# RAILS–undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i cant wrap my head around this problem, need some help :D.
I have one Model name "Recipe", defined Rest and so on... but i wanted to add 1 custom method to the 7 actions of REST. In this case, after save a Recipe it should redirect_to the **createingredient** action (with the :id in the params hash)

In the **createingredient** action, a variable should be define (**@recipe**) by the params[:id]. The prams[:id] exits, but somehow the view could not access to the **@recipe**

```
 def new
  @recipe = Recipe.new
end

def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(params_value)
    if @recipe.save
      redirect_to action: "newingredient",id: @recipe.id, notice: "Recipe succesfully created, time to add Ingredients"
    else
      render "new"
    end
end
```

**the custommethode**

```
  def newingredient
@recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id]) end
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: Which line triggers that error? Please post complete error log in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Change `create` method to

```
def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(params_value)
  if @recipe.save
    redirect_to newingredient_recipe_path(@recipe), notice: "Recipe succesfully created, time to add Ingredients"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

`config/routes.rb`

```
resources :recipes do
  member do
    get :newingredient
  end
end
```

Comment: @Lam Nauyen Tien, If its working perfect you can accept the answer